# Ftp is not prompting for username and password

Tags: linux

I have installed vsftpd and made changes the config file  also but when I type ftp ip it is not prompting me for username and password

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to change the anonymous access lines in vsftpd.conf? If you didn't, here's the solution.

open vsftpd.conf

```
sudo nano vsftpd.conf
```

Look for the lines

```
#Allow anonymous FTP?
#anonymous_enable=NO
```

and then change it so it reads

```
#Allow anonymous FTP?
anonymous_enable=NO
```

Restart the service by

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: I tried editing the config file as you said above but even though it is not prompting for username and password

Comment: Please don't encourage off-topic questions by answering them. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)